# ASP.NET MVC 6 Dependency Injection

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection

I have the code,

```
public class VendorManagementController : Controller
{
    private readonly IVendorRespository _vendorRespository;

    public VendorManagementController()
    {
        _vendorRespository = new VendorRespository();
    }
```

Now I want to use dependency injection. So the code will be

```
public class VendorManagementController : Controller
{
    private readonly IVendorRespository _vendorRespository;

    public VendorManagementController(IVendorRespository vendorRespositor)
    {
        _vendorRespository = vendorRespositor;
    }
```

My question is that I do not find the place where I can create `VendorRespository` object and how I can pass it to the `VendorManagementController` with defined parameterized `VendorManagementController(IVendorRespository vendorRespositor)` constructor?

Comment: Which DI container are you using ?

Comment: @IMU, I have not use any DI container. Should I?

Comment: Yes, for example you can use StructureMap, here is the doc and example of how to use, http://structuremap.github.io/, http://ardalis.com/resolving-dependencies-in-asp.net-mvc-5-with-structuremap

Comment: @IMU DI is built in with MVC6, you don't need a separate DI package

Comment: Cool, I didn't try MVC6. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In MVC6 Dependency Injection is part of the framework - so you don't need Unit, Ninject, etc.

Here's a tutorial: http://dotnetliberty.com/index.php/2015/10/15/asp-net-5-mvc6-dependency-injection-in-6-steps/

Comment: Yes, I just find Startup.cs `public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
             services.AddMvc();
        }`, but I don't know how to put there.

Comment: Have you followed the demo?  It goes through all of the steps.

Answer (score 2):

Dependency injection is baked into ASP.NET MVC 6.  To use it you just need set up your dependencies in the ConfigureServices method of Startup.cs.

The code looks like this:

```
   public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
   {

      // Other code here

      // Single instance in the current scope.  Create a copy of CoordService for this 
      // scope and then always return that instance
      services.AddScoped<CoordService>();

      // Create a new instance created every time the SingleUseClass is requested
      services.AddTransient<SingleUseClass>();

#if DEBUG
      // In debug mode resolve a call to IMailService to return DebugMailService
      services.AddScoped<IMailService, DebugMailService>();
#else
      // When not debugging resolve a call to IMailService to return the 
      // actual MailService rather than the debug version
      services.AddScoped<IMailService, MailService>();
#endif
    }
```

That example code shows a few things:

- The lifecycle of the item you inject can be controlled with AddInstance, AddTransient, AddSingleton and AddScoped
- A compile time `#if` can be used to inject a different object at debug time and runtime.

Lots more info in the [official documentation for ASP.NET MVC 6 Dependency Injection](http://docs.asp.net/projects/mvc/en/latest/controllers/dependency-injection.html?highlight=dependency%20injection), and also a good [basic walk-through here](http://www.davidhayden.me/blog/asp-net-mvc-6-dependency-injection).

Comment: My code is `services.AddTransient<IVendorRespository>();`. Is it right?

Comment: I think you would need to do `services.AddTransient<IVendorRespository, VendorRespository>()`.  That would create a new instance everytime though, you might be better with AddScoped to create a single instance of the repo for the current scope, or even AddSingleton to create a single instance across the whole app.  See more here: http://www.davidhayden.me/blog/asp-net-mvc-6-dependency-injection